# How AWS Application Load Balancer works with WebSocket connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer

My doubt is how it works? The client has a socket connection with the ALB and the ALB has another with the server? Or simply pass through the balancer without making a direct connection with it and not being a load for the balancer?

I want to make it scalable so if exists a limitation with the ALB and the socket connections I would like to know. And when I say limitation I refer to a max number of socket connections at the same time through the balancer.

Also, the stickiness its mandatory in this cases? Does it cause a bad performance to the balancer?